# populate second spinner based on first spinner selection with json data

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner

I have activity which provides some address registration form.
There are regional spinner as follow :

1. Province Spinner
2. City Spinner
3. District Spinner
4. Village Spinner

I already have the way to get data from JSON, here is my goal :
"Populate the City Spinner based on selected item on Province Spinner, and same as the rest for District Spinner and Village Spinner".

I can't post my full java class code here because of privacy issues.

I'm using retrofit 2 for retrieving data from JSON, here is my method that get Province data :

```
private void initSpinnerProvinsi() {
    apiInterface.getProvinsi()
            .enqueue(new Callback<GetProvinsiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GetProvinsiResponse> call, Response<GetProvinsiResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        List<GetProvinsi> provinsiList = response.body().getSemuaprovinsi();
                        List<String> listSpinnerProvinsi = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < provinsiList.size(); i++){
                            listSpinnerProvinsi.add(provinsiList.get(i).getNama());

                            String idkota = provinsiList.get(i).getId();
                            Log.d("idkota ", idkota);
                        }

                        //set result into spinner adapter
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listSpinnerProvinsi);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner_provinsi.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("onResponse: ", "gagal memuat data provinsi");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GetProvinsiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Koneksi gagal, silahkan cek koneksi internet anda",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

and this is my ProvinceSpinner setOnItemSelected method :

```
spinner_provinsi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //request data


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

here is my json data for ProvinceSpinner from postman :

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "Berhasil mendapatkan data provinsi",
  "semuaprovinsi": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "nama": "Aceh"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my json data for CitySpinner from postman :

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "Berhasil mengambil data kabupaten",
  "daftar_kecamatan": [
    {
      "id": "1101",
      "id_prov": "11",
      "nama": "Kab. Simeulue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone please give advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Follow these steps :
a. Populate spinner 1.
b. Hide other spinner.
c. select the item from spinner 1.
d. make service call based on selected item.
e. On success of service call, populate the items in spinner and show the spinner. 
f. follow the step- c till step-e for other spinners.

Comment: yeah so do i know that way, i mean how can i get the 'province_id' based on 'ProvinceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener' so i can retrieve the City Json Data. Because it need 'province_id' as a Path for my Api Interface. 

note : Province Spinner just populate with 'Name', and 'province_id' not populate in Province Spinner as well. So i get confused how to call the City Json Data based on 'ProvinceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener' which just populate with a 'Name' instead the 'province_id'

Comment: get the item from the list passed to spinner based on `position` from `setOnItemSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, check this code :

```
private void initSpinnerProvinsi() {
    apiInterface.getProvinsi()
            .enqueue(new Callback<GetProvinsiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GetProvinsiResponse> call, Response<GetProvinsiResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        final List<GetProvinsi> provinsiList = response.body().getSemuaprovinsi();
                        List<String> listSpinnerProvinsi = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < provinsiList.size(); i++){
                            listSpinnerProvinsi.add(provinsiList.get(i).getNama());
                        }

                        //set result into spinner adapter
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listSpinnerProvinsi);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner_provinsi.setAdapter(adapter);

                        spinner_provinsi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String selectedName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                //request data
                                String idkota = provinsiList.get(position).getId();
                                Log.d("idkota :", idkota);

                                if (selectedName != null)
                                    spinner_kota.setEnabled(true);
                                    initSpinnerKota(idkota);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("onResponse: ", "gagal memuat data provinsi");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GetProvinsiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Koneksi gagal, silahkan cek koneksi internet anda",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```